# Bash program not being found, right in front of my face

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I keep trying to run a bash script in the terminal but it always returns with:

```
No such file or directory
program.sh: line 2: cd: /directory/to/my/program: No such file or directory
program.sh: line 3: ./directory: No such file or directory
```

[image]

Using Ubuntu 20.04.3

Comment: The error is not saying that the `.sh` file cannot be found, but that an `etterna` directory cannot be found in your home directory.

Comment: You don't need to type `bash etternalaunch.sh`, just make the script executable by running `chmod +x etternalaunch.sh` at its directory location (e.g. `~/Downloads/etterna`), then just run `./etternalaunch.sh` and bash will be automatically invoked to run such script. As @matigo explained, bash does execute the script, but then it reads the line 2 of `etternalaunch.sh`, informs you that it didn't find the directory `etterna` at `/home/j0hndoe/`, then it reads the line 3 of `etternalaunch.sh` and informs you that it didn't find `./etterna` (i.e. `~/Downloads/etterna/etterna), either.

Comment: Is there any reason why it wouldn't find the directory? I made the script executable and it still gives me the same error.  I'm new to linux as a whole.

Comment: @butgabba The usual reason for a file or directory to not be found is that it doesn't exist. Other possible reasons would be corruption in the file system, or even a typo in the script. Please [edit] your post to include the output of `ls /home/j0hndoe`

Answer (score 0):

The etternalaunch.sh shell script expects to be run from the parent directory of the etterna directory.  The parent directory of the etterna directory is located at `~/Downloads/`.  Copy the etternalaunch.sh file from the etterna directory to the Downloads directory and run it again.

```
cp ~/Downloads/etterna/etternalaunch.sh ~/Downloads/
cd ~/Downloads/
./etternalaunch.sh
```